# Is downvoting your own question as an alt account, could that get you banned or something?

Tags: discussion

Obviously, upvoting your own question as an alt account is voting fraud, but what if I were to downvote my own question as a sockpuppet? How would that look?

Comment: As you can still get a badge for it (the Peer Pressure one, IIRC), that _might_ count as gaming, I guess...

Comment: still fraud, the direction of the vote isn't what made it fraud

Comment: But could bad stuff happen

Comment: Why do you ask, "theory" only or are you testing the waters? If the latter, I suggest refraining - if you're in doubt, that might mean you know it's wrong... :P

Comment: _"How would that look?"_ - It would look like you don't understand the whole goal of cheating.

Comment: @9098 - The same thing that happens in any voting fraud case.  Sock puppets are typically nuked from orbit.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of either of the two questions. First, it is not asking what they should do if they suspect that a user has a sockpuppet. Second, they are not asking if a sockpuppet/second account is ever legitimate. Ut is asking about a specific type of behavior

Comment: @Mari-LouA The first target's answer very specifically mentions voting on one's own questions as a problem. Both upvoting and downvoting constitute voting.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog the two questions are related, doesn't mean they are duplicates of each other.

Comment: Why in the world would you ever want to downvote your own post? If it's that bad, you probably shouldn't have posted it in the first place.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle If you couldn't delete your own post but wanted it to be deleted by the Roomba, for instance.

Answer (score 12):

The rules state you're not allowed to do anything with multiple accounts that you couldn't do with a single account.  Voting on your own posts is something that you can't do without the additional account, so it's violating the rules.  Maybe no one would care enough to report you or to act on it, or maybe they would, but it's a violation of the rules nonetheless.